# PHP function using mysqli innerjoin

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to receive applications from a mysql database which the user got access to:

**My problem:**

I receive the following error, what could cause this?

```
[Sun Oct 08 13:08:41.194245 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 12486] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/development.xxx.com/modules/database.php:386\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/pr0b.com/development.pr0b.com/authenticated/applications.php(17): database->getApplicationsById(1)\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/development.xxx.com/modules/database.php on line 386\n'
```

**My database structure:**

Table access:

```
id - user_id - product - status - expires
```

Table products:

```
id - name - description - download - role
```

**My function to get the data from the database:**

```
function getApplicationsById($id)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli($this->dBhost, $this->dBusername, $this->dBpassword, $this->dBdatabase);

    if(mysqli_connect_error())
    {
        exit();
        return false;
    }

    $userDataSql = "SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN access products.id = access.product WHERE access.user_id = ?";
    $stmtData = $mysqli->prepare($userDataSql);
    $stmtData->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmtData->execute();
    $result = $stmtData->get_result();
    $rows = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $stmtData->close();
    return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your query. After `join table_name` you have to add `ON` then specify joining columns

change

```
 $userDataSql = "SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN access products.id = access.product WHERE access.user_id = ?";
```

To

```
 $userDataSql = "SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN access ON products.id = access.product WHERE access.user_id = ?";
```

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

Means that your query is returning `false` instead of a dataset.